# Paying from any account to any other via PayPal API

Tags: paypal

I'm trying to figure out whether it is possible to send money directly from any paypal account to any other via PayPal API.

I tried to find the answer in the API documents as hard as I could, but unfortunately haven't found it :-(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two choices: Mass Pay and Adaptive Payments API.

Mass payments is the simplest of the two, and also the old, legacy one (note also it is limited to 250 payments at once).

https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/products/mass-pay

The Adaptive Payments API is the next-generation API, allowing for more complex scenarios and implementations.

https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/products/adaptive-payments

Hope this helps.